# Python Pandas groupby function with dynamic parameters for monthly, hourly means

Tags: python, function, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have an hourly dataframe in the following format over several years:

```
Date/Time            Value
01.03.2010 00:00:00  60
01.03.2010 01:00:00  50
01.03.2010 02:00:00  52
01.03.2010 03:00:00  49
.
.
.
31.12.2013 23:00:00  77
```

and I am using the following code to get the average of each hour for every year in the data:

```
In [11]: year_hour_means = df1.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.hour)).mean()
In [12]: year_hour_means
Out[12]:
           Value
(2010, 0)     60
(2010, 1)     50
(2010, 2)     52
(2010, 3)     49
```

Now I want to put that code into a function, so I am able to dynamically chose to group the hours by quarters, years or months and also do that for a certain daterange of the dataframe.

I have written the following function:

```
def datameans(df, avggrouper1, avggrouper2, startdate, enddate):  
    import pandas as pd
    df_hour_means = df[startdate:enddate]      
    df_hour_means = df_hour_means.groupby(lambda x: (avggrouper1, avggrouper2)).mean()  
    print df_hour_means.to_string()
    df_hour_means.plot()
    pass
```

I am calling the function like this

```
datameans(dataframe, 'x.quarter', 'x.hour' , '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-12-31 23:00:00')
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Can somebody help me how I could have the years, quarters, months and days as different parameters to calculate the means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def datameans(df, avggrouper1, avggrouper2, startdate, enddate):  
    df_hour_means = df[startdate:enddate]      
    df_hour_means = df_hour_means.groupby(
        lambda x: (getattr(x,avggrouper1), getattr(x,avggrouper2))).mean()  
    print df_hour_means.to_string()
    df_hour_means.plot()
```

and (like Matti John's answer) you'd call `datameans` with

```
datameans(dataframe, 'quarter', 'hour' , '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-12-31 23:00:00')
```

---

Alternatively, use [operator.attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
import operator
keyfunc = operator.attrgetter(avggrouper1, avggrouper2)
df_hour_means = df_hour_means.groupby(keyfunc).mean()
```

Comment: great! Many thanks to you both. With this it works perfectly.